# Filtering with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a numeric vector implementation in C; the whole implementation is based on TYPE and then i do s/TYPE/double/g to get an implementation for double and s/TYPE/int/ to get an implementation for int. Up until now I have based the filtering on a tiny sed script which is referenced with an add_custom_command() from the CMakeLists.txt file. That has worked fine on linux, but when trying to generate a Visual Studio solution it fails (in Visual Studio).

Since the process I am performing (search-replace in a file and store the output as a new file) is so simple I thought maybe this could be achieved with builtin CMake commands?

Joakim

Comment: Do you want to generate filtered file as part of the build or file generated by cmake command also works for you?

Comment: I would prefer the file generation to be part of the build process; but I realize can use configure_file() if I am happy with configure time file generations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure cmake you have at least 3 ways to go:

1) `configure_file` command

- is useful for simple replaces, when you only need to substitute some placeholders within the template file based on current project configuration;
- cmake will automatically generate dependency on template file and will regenerate your file on template changes.

2) It is possible to use `FILE READ` or `FILE STRINGS` and `FILE WRITE` commands to make any transformation during the cmake configure step.

- any custom transformation is possible

But

- harder to maintain;
- worth cmake performance;
- no automatic monitoring for template file changes.

3) If it absolutely necessary to generate this file during the build, then you can use cmake in process script mode (`cmake -P`) with `add_custom_command`:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT vector.c
                   COMMAND $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -DTEMPLATE:STRING=vector.template -P genscript.cmake
                   DEPENDS vector.template genscript.cmake)
```

Where `genscript.cmake` is helper script you need to write. It should generate `vector.c` with 1) or 2) approach listened above.

Comment: Thanks a lot 1) is fine for me; as long as dependency on the template is established.